# Length of differential element along a cone.

Tags: differential-geometry

If I calculate the differential length $ds$(see picture) as $rd\varphi$ I get a different value than if I take the projection of $r$ and the projected angle $d\theta$ to get $Rd\theta$ (where $R$ is the projection of $r$).

Does $d\varphi$ not approach $d\theta$ in the limit or does $ds$  not approach $ds'$? What is wrong with my approach? Please help( I'm sorry for my notations).[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $rd\phi$ Is not equal to $ds$.

This is because the radius vector $r$ and the arc segment $ds$ are not in the same circle of plane as you may have assumed.

Comment: Yes but won't the arc segment of the circle approach the arc length $ds$ as $d\varphi$ approaches zero?

Comment: They both approach zero in the limit, but their ratio is not 1